# How to decomplie / compile dll files?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have an app written in C#. It was already compiled.

There are plenty of dll files there and i could not open them , decompile them cannot see and access C# code which build them, when i add a reference to dll files in Visual Studio i only can see what methods are there, but i cannot see / access code of those methods.

Is there a tool or is there a way how to see / access that code , modify it and then recompile it ?

Please if you have an idea give me a hand !

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this is through [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) - it is not perfect, but will give you a good idea.

It lets select an assembly and display it in either IL, vb.net or C#. You can copy/paste the result into Visual Studio and compile it with your changes.

Because it works on the raw optimized IL, things like `foreach` loops can end up as labels and gotos and variables names can end up as invalid C#/vb.net variables names (though they are valid IL).

I have used it in the past, and the biggest issue is in reconstructing `foreach` loops, though the pattern becomes apparent after several of those, and the variable names can be changed with a search/replace.